# Gitlab pipeline: Bad Substitution error in script

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, pipeline

I am trying to set up a pipeline for deployment.  I have my .gitlab-ci.yml set up as follows:

```
deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - staging
  script:
    - files="`cat file-changelist.txt`"
    - file_list=\($files\)
    - for file in "${!file_list[@]}"; do echo "$file"; done
```

But I keep getting "syntax error: bad substitution" on the last line.  I have tried numerous variations, but can't seem to get it right.  My end goal is to be able to do an scp connection and copy files to a server (each file in file_list).

Comment: You're trying to use bash-only array syntax in a script run with `sh`. (Gitlab's runner uses bash when it's available, but `alpine` doesn't provide it by default... which means that tagging this `bash` in the first place isn't quite right).

Comment: ...anyhow, you don't *need* to use arrays for what you're doing here; a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` will do fine.

Comment: (...and `file_list=( $files )` is bad form anyhow, even on shells that *do* support arrays; see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29)).